# Facebook like button error - blocked frame

Tags: jquery, facebook

I'm using jQuery to create dynamic Facebook "Like" buttons. However I'm getting an error that's just repeating itself over and over again.

My jQuery to create the button is:

```
$('#fbLike').html('<fb:like href="'+url+'" send="false" layout="button_count" width="80" show_faces="true" />');
FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('fbLike'));
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.facebook.com" from accessing
a frame with origin "http://localhost:8888".  The frame requesting
access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a
protocol of "http". Protocols must match.
```

Any ideas?

- Edit

  (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

Comment: don't use https if yourself use http

Comment: How do I not user https when connecting to Facebook? I'll edit the above to show all my Facebook related code.

Comment: Configure your local server to run as https://localhost... etc.

Comment: It does that for me too... I think it's a pretty widespread problem. @ronnyfm do you care to elaborate? I have my siteurl set to `http://localhost/appname` right now, I still get those errors. What would you change?

Answer (score 3):

This happens because protocols does not match.

You are trying to create a https frame in http page.

Because of mixed content is disabled on your browser you are seeing that error.

You can enable mixed content on google chrome via command line arg.

```
chrome.exe --allow-running-insecure-content
```

Comment: Disabling this in chrome won't fix the problem though it's just covering it up for the developer. It would probably be a better idea to actually fix the problem by using a secure call on secure pages.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Ian have you tried hitting `https://localhost/appname` and running the call again? If you are running something like XAMPP, LAMP, MAMP your default site should be bound to port 443 (https) hopefully allowing your request protocols to match. If you are still having the same issue you might want to look into trying this from a actual web server (WWW facing) and seeing if the problem persist. Also is there no setting on Facebooks side that you need to enable to allow the use of localhost to their API (swing in the dark here)?